# how to binding images to image control with Eval from defferent folders?

Tags: asp.net, eval, imagebutton

i have a code like the following:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "../Image/Products/1/" + Eval("P_Pic")   %>' />
```

this is for reading image address from folder .imageButton control is inside listview , and data retrive from more than one table and images reside to different folders... it means this part of code :  "../Image/Products/1/" should be different for each table.can you help me to handle this please?thanks note : each table is for different product and this code is because of merging all product for showing

Comment: Hard to understand the question. Why not store the image path in the DB?

Comment: for example i have 6 category of products and visitors with site menu chose a category , go to related page and ...and another option exist that visitor click on show all product .now in beginning i saved each product image in separate folder , so when i want show all product , only encounter one problem , different folders and how to addressing control with run time methods like Eval.

Comment: Use one folder for all images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a way to handle that

```
public string GetImage(object P_Pic )
    {
        if (P_Pic != null & ProductCategory == "a")
        {
            string Pic = "../Image/Products/a/" + P_Pic;
            //do something with the ImageID to return the image path as string
            return Pic;
        }
        else if (P_Pic != null & ProductCategory == "b")
        {
            string Pic = "../Image/Products/b/" + P_Pic;
            return Pic;
        }
        else if (P_Pic != null & ProductCategory == "c")
        {
            string Pic = "../Image/Products/c/" + P_Pic;
            return Pic;
        }
        else if (P_Pic != null & ProductCategory == "d")
        {
            string Pic = "../Image/Products/d/" + P_Pic;
            return Pic;
        }
        else if (P_Pic != null & ProductCategory == "e")
        {
            string Pic = "../Image/Products/e/" + P_Pic;
            return Pic;
        }
        else if (P_Pic != null & ProductCategory == "f")
        {
            string Pic = "../Image/Products/f/" + P_Pic;
            return Pic;
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

where "ProductCategory" is session that passed here.next in control i added this code :

```
<img id="img" class="img" runat="server" src='<%# GetImage(Eval("P_Pic")) %>' />
```

that's All :)

Comment: Omg! - just use : `return P_Pic != null ? $"../Image/Products/{ProductCategory}/{P_Pic}" : "";` instead ;).